# Multi row aggregation select result includes whole object hydrated as well

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

On Symfony2 I have an entity called `Product` which is managed by Doctrine2 and being related with a single category and location.

```
Class Product {
  protected $id;
  protected $title;
  // n additional fields
  protected $productCategory;
  protected $productDepot;
}
```

What I need to achieve is, select category and location COUNT's in a single query.

So I'm executing the following `COUNT` select with some groupings on the following DQL.

```
$this->em->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:Product')
  ->createQueryBuilder('P')
  ->addSelect('IDENTITY(P.productCategory) AS category_id')
  ->addSelect('IDENTITY(P.productDepot) AS location_id')
  ->addSelect("COUNT(P.id) AS tag_count")
  ->addGroupBy('P.productCategory')
  ->addGroupBy('P.productDepot')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getScalarResult();
```

However when it is executed, the whole result is as follows:

```
 $result = [
    0 => [
       P_id => ...,
       P_title => ...,
       P_stock => ....,
       /*
        * Many many additional fields of the entity
        */
       category_id => 15,
       location_id => 40,
       tag_count => 20
    ],
    ...
 ];
```

However obviously I just need `category_id`, `location_id` and `tag_count` fields. Since the table is a huge one (like everyone has one, nowadays), I'm trying to minimize footprint of the query as much as possible.

What I tried so far is adding a partial field of `id` (as follows) however it didn't make sense.

```
$this->em->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:Product')
  ->createQueryBuilder('P')
  ->addSelect('partial P.{id}')
  ->addSelect('IDENTITY(P.productCategory) AS category_id')
  ->addSelect('IDENTITY(P.productDepot) AS location_id')
  ->addSelect("COUNT(P.id) AS tag_count")
  ->addGroupBy('P.productCategory')
  ->addGroupBy('P.productDepot')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getScalarResult();
```

Am I trying to achieve something impossible, or do you have any idea to get just the aggregation fields (or with just an additonal ID field) of an an entity?